# beautifulsoup .select returns nothing

Tags: python, html, ubuntu, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I'm an amateur python user. Currently I'm trying to figure out the beautiful soup module, but i can't get the select method to find anything.
I have made and example html file (more or less coppied from the book "automate the boring stuff with python") the content of which is:

```
<html><head><title>The Website Title</title></head>
<body>
<p><strong>Hi There!</strong> here is a link to a website: <a href="http://
inventwithpython.com">a website thing</a>.</p>
<p class="slogan">this is a roundup, this is a low flying panic attack.</p>
<p>By <span id="author">Yonatan.</span></p>
</body></html>
```

I've entered this code into the shell:

```
examplefile = open('example.html')
examplesoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(examplefile.read())
elem = examplesoup.select('#author')
```

but what i get as elem is an empty list. I've checked examplefile.read() and its the real thing. also tried select('p') and got nothing.
is there something very obvious that I'm missing here? I'm also new to html.

Comment: This works fine for me. There's a problem with your file contents. I hope you're doing `print(elem)`.

Comment: i am. what do you mean a problem with my file contents? the html or the script?
by the way, it works beautifully on requests objects passed through .text.

Comment: `'example.html'` ...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
examplefile = open('example.html')
myfile=examplefile.read()
examplesoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(myfile)
elem = examplesoup.select('#author')
```

this should work.

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer. Why to try this? What was the problem with OPs try that this fixes?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18017597)

Comment: @SebastianGodelet this is definitely not a link-only answer; for one, there are no links in the answer. However, as pirho said, this answer definitely needs improvement/explanations

Comment: @Sagar, sorry I think I selected the wrong thing during the review process

Comment: @SebastianGodelet that's ok! Props for reviewing, though! :)